# Transforming nested Markdown into HTML using Java

Tags: java, html, string, transform

I need to transform strings one into another.
An example is:

```
#Fashion #Helmet #Woman #Scifi [ ![t](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbv08xkdzy1qfzis2o1_1280.gif) ](http://bit.ly/P1omax) Rob Goodwin
```

That has to be transformed into the HTML code:

```
#Fashion #Helmet #Woman #Scifi<a href="http://bit.ly/P1omax"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbv08xkdzy1qfzis2o1_1280.gif" /></a>
```

Is there a Java library that does that?

---

**UPDATE**

It looks very similar to Markdown. But processing it with markdownj produces a messy HTML:

```
<h1>Fashion #Helmet #Woman #Scifi</h1>

<p><a href="a href="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbv08xkdzy1qfzis2o1_1280.gif">http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbv08xkdzy1qfzis2o1_1280.gif</a"> <img src="<a href="http://bit.ly/P1omax">http://bit.ly/P1omax</a>" alt="t</a> " />
Rob Goodwin</p>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

All three Java libraries that allow to transform Markdown into HTML have problems recognising images inside links.

The approach that I decided to use is a two-step approach:

- run your library;
- use Java code to correct the errors.

It is not an ideal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the inputstring markdown? Yes it works in http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus which generates

```
<h1>Fashion #Helmet #Woman #Scifi <a href="http://bit.ly/P1omax"> <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbv08xkdzy1qfzis2o1_1280.gif" alt="t" title="" /> </a> Rob Goodwin</h1>
```

Therefore: http://code.google.com/p/markdownj/
Or: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Markdown_implementations

https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown looks ok. they claim:

> [pegdown] fully passes the original Markdown test suite

Comment: If not explicitly markdown, there are other wiki formats... I wish I could remember the project name but there was an Eclipse project that provided a library for various wiki format conversions. Maybe related to the Mylyn plugin.

Comment: It is similar to markdown, but using the library that you have provided produces some messy HTML code.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij which lib did you finally use? I would be interested in the outcome ;)

Comment: I guess that the original Markdown test suite does not test nested elements, like images inside links, that unfortunately are frequent in my case. So I will have to write java code to correct such cases. Take a look at the update of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to extract the URLs from the text, and then concatenate into a template output string.

There are many examples of the regex needed to extract URLS, [this for example](http://blog.houen.net/java-get-url-from-string/).

Using the above method, you could write something like:

```
String[] split = yourInput.split("[ ![t](");
String[] urls = pullLinks(yourInput)
String output = split[0] + "<a href=\"" + urls[1] + "\"><img src=\"" + urls[0] + "\" /></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look at using XSLT. Java includes XSLT as part of the JAXP library and this will allow you to define pattern matching and transformation rules, using XSL, and apply them to input text. Eclipse has an excellent tool to allow you to build and test XSL.

Comment: Input is absolutely non-XML, so XML tools wouldn't be a good fit i guess.

Comment: Isn't XSLT used for transforming XML compliant text?